# Entity framework core multi tenant : auto increment column based in another column value

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, multi-tenant, .net-6.0

Using entity framework core 6 with sample class

```
public class Sample
{
  [Key]
  public long Id { get; set; }
  public long TenantId { get; set; }
  public long PartitionId { get; set; } 
}
```

I need to make auto increment of partition id based in brand id.

First I add index mapper between tenantId and partitionId to make sure never duplicated than i used in partitionId `ValueGeneratedOnAdd()` function, my missing part how i can make auto generation of partitionId  foreach tenantId in sequence.

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Sample>(builder =>
        {

            // enable unique partion id based in tenant level
            builder.HasIndex(r => new { r.PartitionId, r.TenantId }).HasDatabaseName("IX_Sample_PartitionId").IsUnique();

            builder.ToTable("Sample").Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnOrder(0);

            builder.ToTable("Sample").Property(p => p.TenantId ).HasColumnOrder(1);

            // create auto increment base in brand id
            builder.ToTable("Sample").Property(p => p.PartitionId).ValueGeneratedOnAdd().HasColumnOrder(2);

       });
```

Required result should be like this

```
Id | TenantId | PartitionId 
1  | 1        | 1
2  | 1        | 2
3  | 2        | 1
4  | 2        | 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by having a difference sequence for each tenant and you script it as part of the tenant onboarding.

ex:
When you create a tenant, you run the following script:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE [dbo].[Tenant{0}_PartionIdSequence] AS [int] START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1
```

When you insert ar ecord to the sample table, you will have to call this script tp get the next value for PartitionId

```
SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.[Tenant{0}_PartionIdSequence]
```

This way every tenant should have its own sequence

Comment: Tenant table not having PartitionId, even if it is added  'Tenant{0}_PartionIdSequence' will be responsible for Tenant table not Sample, my case need to have sequence of PartionId based in TenantId within Sample table

Comment: You can either do the same in other tables or simply use a prefix for the column you want to have unique values for each tenant. Ex: if you have an Order table you can have OrderNumbe as O-{TenantId}-{Auto Increment Number}

Comment: Thank you for efforts, tested still not working, if it is possible to modify the code above and provide a complete solution would be great!

Comment: The sequence creation needs to happen when you create a new tenant and not in the Model builder. If you have a new tenant with id 1 then the string Tenant{0}_PartionIdSequence should be evaluated to Tenant1_PartionIdSequence

Comment: in this case going to have thousands of sequences since i created for each tenant and this not recommended, my case need to make something related relationship on table level between tenant and his sequence It's created while creating the database in code first.

Comment: Were you ever able to figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Not working, sequence has been created
please note i'm using Postgres SQL, `SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR` statement not correct syntax in my case.

Please find below my changes.

```
   // create sequence for partition id and  map it in tenant level
   modelBuilder.HasSequence<long>("Tenant{0}_PartitionId_seq")
               .StartsAt(1)
               .IncrementsBy(1);

   modelBuilder.Entity<Sample>(builder =>
   {
        // enable unique partion id based in tenant level
        builder.HasIndex(r => new { r.PartitionId, r.TenantId })
               .HasDatabaseName("IX_Sample_PartitionId")
               .IsUnique();

       builder.ToTable("Sample").Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnOrder(0);
       builder.ToTable("Sample").Property(p => p.TenantId).HasColumnOrder(1);

       // mapping sequence table which consider tenant id
       builder.ToTable("Sample").Property(p => p.PartitionId)
             .HasDefaultValueSql("nextval('\"Tenant{0}_PartitionId_seq\"')")
             .HasColumnOrder(2);
   });
```